# Paragraph not working for shortcodes and div

Tags: wordpress

I've been looking to use various Youtube video plugins on my Wordpress site in order to be able to automatically make the videos responsive.

Using the standard iframe embed code  from Youtube will display the videos fine. Proper paragraph is added relative to the text below. This happens automatically. So, when I use  or  to display images or videos, all is fine with proper paragraph.

Strangely though, if I use brackets/shortcode or  to display image or video, paragraph is not respected.

I tried this on my other page which uses the same theme and the same page builder and all works well there, so obviously something is broken on my site.

For me this is like looking for a needle in a haystack, but I have tried disabling the plugins one by one which did not help. I've also tried to look in my child theme css where I do the changes, but could not see anything directly that seemed related to this.

Any suggestions what else I could try?

Comment: Did some more digging with the inspector tool and can see that the <p> only adds space at the bottom while on my other site that is displaying videos fine <p> adds space both to top and bottom.

Comment: I fixed it! .textwidget p in style.css was set to 0px instead of 20px. Jeez.